# Exception in wildfly 10: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have a maven project that works fine in wildfly-8.2, but when I deployed it in wildfly-10, I am getting error -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.workWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper.<init>(XMLHelper.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
```

I searched on the internet about this error and got many posts on this error. I tried many but no luck. I checked wildfly-10 and my application and both have dom4j-1.6.1.jar. Firstly, I removed dom4j-1.6.1.jar from my application and I got a compilation error. Then, I removed dom4j-1.6.1 from JBOSS module and JBOSS started to throw me exception at the start up.

My pom.xml is -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.rolta.oneview.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>OV-PLF</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>platform-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>platform-war</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-webflow -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rolta.oneview.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>license-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rolta.oneview.products.processMgr</groupId>
            <artifactId>agent.api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <!-- RESTeasy -->
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rolta.oneview.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>msg-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rolta.iperspective.sso</groupId>
            <artifactId>iPerspectiveSSO</artifactId>
            <version>5.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ws02</groupId>
            <artifactId>wso2Agent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rolta.aladdin</groupId>
            <artifactId>safenet-sentinel-hasp-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.santuario/xmlsec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>platform</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Jboss-deployment-structure.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>

        <exclusions>
                <module name="org.dom4j" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.rolta.platform" />
            <module name="com.rolta.wso2" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Please let me know, What changes should i do to come out of this problem. Thanks

Comment: Did you try stating the dependency to `provided`? This kind of issue can for instance arise because two same classes are loaded by different class loaders. By putting the dependency provided, you remove the JAR from your WAR, removing the JAR duplication.

Comment: @Tome - I just added provided in my pom.xml. I didnt removed jar because JBOSS and my war both have the different version of the same jar file.

Comment: Adding provided will remove the JAR from your WAR. But indeed then you will have to use the version provided by the app server. Another solution could be to configure the app server class loading behavior, I guess that is what you already tried with the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml simply excluded the dom4j from my hibernate dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.CR1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```